# Camera-facing texture distorted by object dimensions

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to create an image texture that is always facing the camera, almost as if the object it's wrapped around is a mask that shows where the image can be, but the image texture is distorted by the orientation of the object.

[image]
[image]

This is my node setup. Can anyone help me out? I don't want the block to be a literal mask because I plan on creating a scene with lots of blocks that have unique images on them.

Comment: If you dont want it to distort, use _Window_ instead of _Camera_ from the _Texture Coordinate_ node.

Comment: That's true, but I'm also trying to find a solution where the texture moves with the object as well.